# Tortoisehg icons not showing

Tags: windows, mercurial, icons, overlay, tortoisehg

I copied a repository (whole folder) from one computer to another and added the repository to the TortoiseHG workbench through File->Open Repository.

Everything works fine, except no overlay icons are showing in windows explorer in the directory of the copied repository (for whether the file has been modified, or it's up to date, etc).
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, please [edit] it out of the "Question" post and add an "Answer" post below. Make sure your post here fully answers the question (and cite the source). Self answers [are enouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/3933/overlay-icons-not-showing-properly - see Shea Martin's reply near the bottom about windows only allowing 11 overlay icon registry entries

Comment: The page no longer exists but here's an archived version from The Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20200706203000/https://WSMcG@bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/3933/overlay-icons-not-showing-properly